# Proper usage of INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I am considering using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for my application which routinely has to submit many rows to the database in one transaction. However I am slightly confused regarding one thing. The usage examples online seem to be many in their variations for this functionality.

The behavior I am looking for is that I want to Insert the row if it does not already exist in the unique index, but if it does exist I simply want to return the ID but update nothing. Am I correct in assuming that this is the intended functionality for this statement.

Also I don't want to go creating dummy fields in my tables to utilize this functionality, as is suggested in many examples. That in my opinion is just bad practice.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Below is an example from mysql's website that illustrates close to what I want but the c=3 part is not explained on it. I am wondering if this is required to make the last_insert_id actually work or if its just part of their example. I have read that without some dummy operation after the last_insert_id part then the last_insert_id won't work.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can just `SELECT` the unique ID to determine whether it exists.  If it does, just return it.  Otherwise, do the `INSERT` and return the new ID.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a single statement in MySQL. A `SELECT` statement returns existing values; data modification statements (including `INSERT`) do not return data. (They usually return a count of some sort.) This includes the `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement—it does not return data.

You can probably do what you want with a stored procedure, but the procedure will contain more than one statement. If that doesn't work for you, then do as @Explosion Pills suggests and use a `SELECT` followed, if needed, by an `INSERT`.